# Как найти сумму элементов многомерного массива?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нам дан одномерный и многомерный массив, нам нужно посчитать сумму элементов массива в таком порядке.элемент массива надо добавить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -2):

Если количество элементов в массиве `arr` равно количеству элементов в массиве `md2`, тогда можно просто перебрать массивы припомни цикла for, и затем уже использовать полученные данные. Привел пример того, как можно это реализовать:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
        
var md2 = [
    [2, 1, 2],
    [1, 1, 0],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 1, 2]
];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for(var j = 0; j < md2.length; j++) {
        sum += arr[i] * md2[j][i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```